How to install window on Ubuntu vps
Hi i need of help to install a Windows 2019 template on Vultr bare metal server
but I don't know the steps. Can someone here help me?

This site is for Ubuntu support only. So no and sorry Windows questions are off topic.

Contact Microsoft Support
